# Linking against two lib files that have the same function signature?

Tags: c, windows, static-libraries, static-linking

If I am using a function that has the following signature:

`void foo(int i);`

And this function exists in libxxx.lib and also in libyyy.lib (but the implementation for the function is different in each lib file), so what happens if I link my object file against these two lib files? Will I get an error that the function exists in both lib files or will the linker choose a random function or something else?

Comment: How could the linker choose a random function? that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sounds like you need to start using namespaces.

Comment: Is it c or c++, you should pick one, because the are different.

Comment: One question ... why don't you try? There are three options. Linker error, last symbol will be used, first symbol will be used.

Comment: @luk32: actually there's a fourth option: it will behave unpredictably.  Even worse, it might seem to be predictable, but break at some point in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally a linker should only get unresolved symbols from a static library. So if the function `void foo(int i)` is called from one of the object files given to the linker, it will use the version present in first library given in the command line. Because once the symbol has been found in first library, it is no longer unresolved when looking at second one.

It would be different if same symbol was defined in two object files, because it would lead to a linker error.

And the problem is hard to solve if the function `void foo(int i)` is called from another static library, because now it depends on the relative order of the 3 libraries. My advice is that if you can, you should avoid that corner case.

Comment: if the function were defined in two object files, and if the two functions were defined as 'globally visible' then a linker error would result, however if one or both of the functions were defined as 'static' then no linker error

Comment: IIRC, on the command line, Microsoft's linker allows you to specify a static library either as a library (i.e., so that it is added only if needed) or as one of the source files (in which case it is added no matter what).  If you do the latter for the preferred library I believe it should ensure that the correct function is used.  (OTOH, I'm not sure offhand how you'd configure Visual Studio to generate the right command line.)